# Using .htaccess to redirect to relative address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am very new to URL rewriting using .htaccess and I would like to redirect anyone entering the domain below

```
http://domain.tld/admin
```

to be redirected to

```
http://domain.tld/index.php?section=admin
```

but without including the full address. This is the code I am using but it doesnt seem to work

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin /index.php?section=admin
</IfModule>
```

Where Im I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Also, do you want a HTTP redirect or just a rewrite of the url? You might want to look into the modifier flags at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this more correct regex rule with `L` flag:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin/? index.php?section=admin [L,QSA,NC]
```